# How to use flask-admin to trim white spaces from the field data in admin forms

Tags: python, mongodb, validation, flask-admin

I am using flask-admin to provide admin interface for creating and editing Models. I want to put in a validation to stop user entering a string field with white spaces at the start or end OR I should be able to trim these whitespaces before saving to database.

I appreciate any help regarding this.

Regards,
Shameer

Answer (score 0):

figured out..here is the answer.

```
def isclean(val):
    if val != val.strip():
        raise ValidationError("Do not Use space at start or end of text.")

class Test(db.Document):
    test= db.StringField(db_field="tes", required=True, unique=True, validation=isclean)
```